# AngularJs "Collapse" | ng-repeat multiple accordions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two accordions using the same function called "`collapse`", this is part of bootstrap.

The issue I'm having is that on click both accordions open at the same time - this is not what I'm after.

What I think is going on is that both accordions are using the same function with no differentiator like an ID or get by element.

I'm unsure how to make it so that if a user clicks on the accordion, only the clicked accordion opens.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="connections-wrap" ng-class="{'accordion-active': active}" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed; toggleClass()" ng-init="isCollapsed = true">
                    <span class="connection-amount">{{billingAccount.totalSharers}}</span>
                    <span class="connection-type">Shared connections</span>
                    <div class="account-summary-icon-set-3 task-left connection-chevron"></div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- {{connection}} -->

                  <ul class="connections-list connection-list-first collapse" collapse="isCollapsed">
                    <li ng-repeat="sharedConnection in billingAccount.connections['sharers']">
                      <span class="connection-device">{{sharedConnection.nameTwo}}</span>
                      <span class="connection-number">{{sharedConnection.billingAccountNumber}}</span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <div class="connections-wrap">
                    <span class="connection-amount">{{billingAccount.totalOthers}}</span>
                    <span class="connection-type">Other connections</span>
                    <div class="account-summary-icon-set-3 task-left connection-chevron"></div>
                  </div>


                  <ul class="connections-list collapse" collapse="isCollapsed">
                    <li ng-repeat="otherConnection in billingAccount.connections['others']">
                      <span class="connection-device">{{otherConnection.nameTwo}}</span>
                      <span class="connection-number">{{otherConnection.billingAccountNumber}}</span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `isCollapsed` scope variable in multiple places. Use different variables to control the accordians independentaly

Comment: I've tried changing this variable like you've suggested and I lose functionality - unsure why.

Comment: You lose functionality because the click even only toggles the isCollapsed. You will need to add a bit more logic to control the other variables.